# Updating media volume by using range input and without using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code

`<input type="range" value="0.5" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" onchange="myFunction(this)">`

---

which is supposed to manage the audio of a music track. When changed, the value gets parsed into **float** with `parseFloat(value)` and updates my script's internal value that determines the volume of the track. I can obviously hard-code and it works, but I need to use the inputs to make it user-reliable. Console.logging it logs the correct value upon every change, but it does not change the volume and I get the error

> Type Error: Value being assigned to HTMLMediaElement.volume is not a finite floating-point value.

Comment: can you show the code for `myFunction`?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Just get the value of input range using javascript and set it to mediaElement.volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the volume of any `HTMLMediaElement` you should keep track of these events:

1. `onloadedmetadata` of media element
2. `onchange` of range input
3. `ontimeupdate` of media element

```js
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var maxVol;

video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  input.max = video.duration;
}

input.onchange = function() {
  video.currentTime = input.value;
}

video.ontimeupdate = function() {
  input.value = video.currentTime;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <video controls autoplay>
    <source src='https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2014_12/preview/mlky_6.mp453110.webm'>
  </video>
  
  <input type="range" value="0.5" min='0' step='0.1'>
</body>
</html>
```